# How to list the Mail directory from the Terminal?

Tags: terminal, permission, filesystem

Is there a way to change the file or directory permissions so that I can list the contents of the Mail directory from the Terminal command-line in macOS 10.15.4?

When trying to list the contents, I currently get this error.

```
$ cd ~/Library/Mail 
$ ls -l 
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

The Mail app works without issues.  I can see the contents of the Mail folder in the Finder by using the Option key.  On earlier macOS versions, I could list the contents from the Terminal without issues.  But not any more after migrating to a new MacBook Pro running 10.15.4.  What changed?

Comment: I need to get a directory listing so that I can run rsync to my linux backup server.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give Terminal Full Disk Access in System Preferences > Security.